# Is there a proof via Chern-Weil theory that the first Chern numbers of two $\mathbb R$-isomorphic complex vector bundles are equal mod 2?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be a compact, oriented surface.
If we have a complex vector bundle $E$ over $M$, then we can define the first Chern number $c_1(E)$ via Chern-Weil theory. More precisely, if $\nabla$ is a connection on $E$, then for a local frame $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ we can define the $1$-forms $A_j^i$ by the formula
$$\nabla u_j = \sum_i A_j^i u_i,
$$
and then define the curvature by
$$F := dA + A \wedge A,$$
where
$A$ is the matrix $(A_j^i)$ of $1$-forms.

The first Chern number is defined by
$$c_1(E) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_M \mathrm{tr}(F),$$
and this number does not depend on the choice of connection $\nabla$.

Two complex vector bundles $E_1, E_2$ are $\mathbb C$-isomorphic if there is a diffeomorphism $f:E_1 \to E_2$ such that the diagram

[image]

commutes and $f$ restricted to the fibers is $\mathbb C$-linear. Analogously, the complex vector bundles are $\mathbb R$-isomorphic if the map $f$ restricted to the fibers is $\mathbb R$-linear.

If the $E_1$ and $E_2$ are $\mathbb C$-isomorphic, then $c_1(E_1) = c_1(E_2)$, and if they are $\mathbb R$-isomorphic, then $c_1(E_1) = c_1(E_2) \mod 2$.

Nevertheless, I only know how to prove the second property via Stiefel–Whitney numbers: in short, we have $c_1(E_1) = w_2(E_1) \mod 2$.

> **Question:** If $f:E_1 \to E_2$ is an $\mathbb R$-isomorphism, how do I prove $c_1(E_1) = c_1(E_2) \mod 2$ direct from Chern-Weil approach, without using general characteristic classes?

If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are line bundles, then the proof is actually simple, because in this case we have $$c_1(E) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_M F,$$
that coincides it the Euler number, and it is easy to prove that $c_1(E_1) = c_1(E_2)$ if $f$ preserves orientation, and $c_1(E_1) = -c_1(E_2)$ if $f$ reverses the orientation.

I would be satisfied with a proof for rank $2$.

Comment: One proof is to use the fact that $c_1(E) = c_1(\bigwedge^nE)$, but I'm not sure if you would be satisfied by this argument.

Comment: Nice! I'm very happy with that argument, because we obtain $c_1(E_1) = c_1(E_2)$ if $\wedge^n(f):\wedge^nE_1 \to \wedge^nE_2$ preserves orientation, and $c_1(E_1) = -c_1(E_2)$ otherwise. It's much better than just $\mod 2$.

Comment: It will never exist a case where $c_1(E_1) = c_1(E_2)+2$ for example.

Comment: Thank you very much! @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm having problem with a detail. If we have a $\mathbb R$-isomorphism $f:E_1 \to E_2$ why are the bundles $\wedge^n E_1$ and $\wedge^n E_2$ $\mathbb R$-isomorphic? That is clear if $f$ is $\mathbb C$-linear because we can consider the isomorphism $\wedge^n f$, but that morphism does not make sense for $\mathbb R$-linear.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think my comment through carefully enough, sorry.